# Updating a Wicket WebMarkupContainer

Tags: java, wicket

Inside my Wicket webpage, I have a WebMarkupContainer which contains a `ListView`:

```
notifications = new ArrayList<Notification>(...);
ListView listView = new ListView("notification", notifications) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
        ...
    }
};

container = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
container.setOutputMarkupId(true);
container.add(listView);
this.add(container);
```

The `WebMarkupContainer` is in place in order to let me dynamically update the list of items shown to the user onscreen. This is possible when the user clicks on a link or by adding the container to incoming `AjaxRequestTarget`.

Now I'm required to update the list without having an Ajax request:

```
public void refresh() {
    List<Notification> newNotifications = ... 
    notifications.addAll(0, newNotifications);
}
```

This method is called in a run-time environment and the list of notifications, which is a private field of my webpage (same one as last code), will contain new objects. I want these new items displayed to the user. Is it possible to update (or re-render) the container?

I'm new to Wicket so if you have a better way to achieve the same results, I would appreciate if you could share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do it on a timer. Use [AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html) to do so. Just set some sensible duration and add your container to target in  'onTimer()' method.

EDIT:

If your 'refresh()' function is only called when new notifications appear, you could set a flag on your page (define boolean variable on page and change it to true when new notification appears and to false once listView is refreshed). Then you can set short duration on the behavior and 'onTimer()' would look something like that:

```
onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    if(newNotifications) {
        target.add(container);
        newNotifications = false;
    }
}
```

And refresh

```
public void refresh() {
    List<Notification> newNotifications = ... 
    notifications.addAll(0, newNotifications);
    newNotifiactions = true;
}
```

That way container won't be refreshed too often (which might cause strange effects) and will refresh every time new notification appears.

Comment: Thanks for your response. surely it is possible to do so by adding the time behavior as you've instructed but fetching new notifications in refresh() method is an expensive operation involving data access layer so i rather not do the same process over and over again and for each user. what i'm sure about is when user have a new notification the refresh method will be called.

Comment: OK, by implementing your revision we will avoid unnecessary refreshes on the container. As it seems there are no way avoiding repeating the process on a periodic basis. Thanks again for your response.